# SolAdmin says "Coming Soon" on all pages

Tags: user-interface, solace

[image]Ive recently setup a Solace VMR in AWS. I logged in to the SolAdmin GUI on port 8080. I was able to get authenticated with an admin account I created via the CLI, however on all the pages it just says "Coming Soon"

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is not SolAdmin but an alpha preview of a web-based UI. Only a handful of objects are available for testing the look-and-feel of the new UI.

To manage the VMR effectively, use SolAdmin instead. Download it via:
http://dev.solace.com/downloads/

Comment: If I'm using the community version of the VMR, can I still use SolAdmin for free with no time limit?

Comment: The freely downloadable SolAdmin is an evaluation edition with time limit, and that is independent of whatever VMR editions you're using. Alternatively, you can get acquainted with the CLI: http://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing-Routers/Using-the-Solace-Router-CLI.htm